# Set type for entire const block

Tags: go, types, constants

I have a custom data type

`type Custom string`

And a const block

```
const (
    Item1 = "placeholder"
    ...
    Item10 = "placeholder"
)
```

Is it possible to set the type Custom the every item in the const block, without having to place it in every entry?

Comment: Only with `iota` constants, which are number based, so with strings you have to specify the type for each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spec: Constant declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations)

> ```
> ConstDecl      = "const" ( ConstSpec | "(" { ConstSpec ";" } ")" ) .
> ConstSpec      = IdentifierList [ [ Type ] "=" ExpressionList ] .
> ```

A constant declaration is a series of constant specifications, where each contains the optional type.

One thing that may be exploited is:

> Within a parenthesized `const` declaration list the expression list may be omitted from any but the first ConstSpec. Such an empty list is equivalent to the textual substitution of the first preceding non-empty expression list and its type if any. **Omitting the list of expressions is therefore equivalent to repeating the previous list.** The number of identifiers must be equal to the number of expressions in the previous list. Together with the [`iota` constant generator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota) this mechanism permits light-weight declaration of sequential values...

So for example in the below example both `Item1` and `Item2` will be of type `Custom`:

```
const (
    Item1 Custom = "v1"
    Item2
)
```

The problem here is that both `Item1` and `Item2` will have the same `"v1"` value. This isn't really useful unless you use the `iota` in the expression.

One way to only specify the type once is to list the identifier before the values:

```
const (
    Item1, Item2 Custom = "v1", "v2"
)
```

In the example above both `Item1` and `Item2` will be of type `Custom`, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/c6mjN6ikgkp). The disadvantage here is that the identifier may "get far" from its value, this is less readable than listing them on separate lines:

```
const (
    Item1 Custom = "v1"
    Item2 Custom = "v2"
)
```

Alternatively you may "move the type" to the expression, using a typed constant value:

```
const (
    Item1 = Custom("v1")
    Item2 = Custom("v2")
)
```